# Remove duplicate rows in a array using id using C#

Tags: c#

I have to remove duplicate rows in a array using id using C#. In the array I have 3 columns.

Following is my code

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetYesterdayPatientsByTime()
{
    try
    {

            BusinessLogicLayer bal = new BusinessLogicLayer();
            DataSet ds = bal.GetYesterdayPatientsByTimeBAL();
            string[] output = new string[(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count * ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count)];

            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    output[count++] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                }
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            js.MaxJsonLength = 2147483644;
            return js.Serialize(output.Distinct().ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "";
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: that distinct method is removing same names in that "output" array with different id's.pls let me know how to make it

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the `Distinct()` method into `DistinctBy()`, which will allow You to distinct by several columns - check link: [LINQ's Distinct() on a particular property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property)

Another solution that came in my mind is create ArrayList with the results. While going through whole array, You will check if the element does exist in list, and if not You will add it.

After checking MSDN - https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx - You can find that `Distinct()` by default using `Default IEquatable`, so You can also add own `Comparer` to the class, which will compare based on ID.